# Slicing, with nothing to slice

Tags: c++

If I have code like the following:

```
class Base { /* ... */};
class Derived : public Base { /* ... */ };

 int main() {
    Base b = Derived{};
 }
```

Then the code exhibits the *slicing problem*.  Any data that is part of class `Derived` but not part of class `Base` is lost.  But suppose that `Derived` doesn't have any data members or base classes that aren't in `Base`, so there is no data to lose.

Does this code still exhibit undefined behavior or other problems?

Comment: No, there's no undefined behavior here.

Comment: Slicing doesn't cause undefined behavior. It's simply what happens when you copy a derived class into a base class object - you lose the "derivedness".

Comment: In this example, you could simply make the type of B derived, as you know it.

Comment: There is no data to lose, but don't forget virtual functions to lose.

Comment: The only question here would be: why would you need a derived class that is completely identical to its base? I realize you're asking a theoretical question, but still.

Answer (score 4):

Normally speaking slicing doesn't have undefined behavior: It usually just doesn't do what you WANT it to do. In this case I can't see any problems, although I also can't see why you would need a child class that didn't add anything to the base.

Comment: One use case would be if you have read-only handle and mutating handle classes. It makes sense that mutating handle extends the read-only one while only adding functionality (and no data members).

Comment: @rburny Unless I'm missing something (which is possible) a "writable handle" fails both the is-a and substitutability tests for inheritance.

Comment: I don't see the problem. "Writable handle" can be used as a "readonly handle" if you only use const methods. It's "writable", not "write-only".